# MySQL : Selecting values from a specific column is very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, select, innodb, where-clause

I have a mysql database called `key_word`. It has 3 columns, 23 million rows.

Please have a look at the below query.

```
SELECT `indexVal` FROM `key_word` WHERE `hashed_word`='001'
```

This query takes around 6 seconds to display me the result. Result contains 169669 rows. This is very very slow. However, I have noticed that this occurs "only" if I trying to get records in `indexVal`. All the below queries are very fast.

```
SELECT `primary_key` FROM `key_word` WHERE `hashed_word`='001'
SELECT `hashed_word` FROM `key_word` WHERE `indexVal`=0
```

All these 3 columns are indexed separatly, so I don't understand why it is slow when I am trying to get data from `indexVal` by searching `hashed_word`

Below is my Table structure.

[image]

Below is some more information about the table

[image]

So, why this selecting from `indexVal` while searching from `hashed_word` is slow? How can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

As requested, I am posting the result of

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `indexVal` FROM `key_word` WHERE `hashed_word`='001'
```

below

[image]

**UPDATE**

The result of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%query_cache_size%';    SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%query_cache_type%';` is below

[image]

Comment: Run `explain select indexval from ...` and add the results please.

Comment: How many rows do the two faster queries return?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thank you for the reply. The query `SELECT 'primary_key' FROM 'key_word' WHERE 'hashed_word'='001'` returns 169669 rows very very fast.

Comment: @juergend: Thank you for the reply. I updated my question with the requested information.

Comment: What happens when you run `select distinct indexval ...`?

Comment: @juergend: No difference, slow as above.

Comment: Can you try adding a `order by primary_key` and try the select?

Comment: @Akhil: Tried, no difference.

Comment: Please let me know the result of the below queries `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%query_cache_size%';
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%query_cache_type%';`

Comment: It is "off". I updated the question with the images.

Comment: Is the data actually loaded in order by `IndexVal`, as suggested by the sample data?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: You mean the "data" image I have provided? No, it is not a result image, it is a image you see when you "browse"

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Can you change the data type to bigint(20) for index_val column and try? (Make sure you dont mess up the production system) :) . this is just to identify the root cause

Comment: Try this statement too `OPTIMIZE TABLE key_word`

Comment: Does `SELECT hashed_word FROM `key_word` WHERE indexVal=0` also return 169669 rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT primary_key FROM key_word WHERE hashed_word='001'` is faster than `SELECT indexVal FROM key_word WHERE hashed_word='001'` because in InnoDB the primary key value is always included in any secondary index; this means that primary_key is read from the index. In the second query however, MySQL first reads the primary key from the index, than it reads the value of indexVal from the table row. In other words it persoms 2x disk reads.

Comment: OK. So, how I can improve mine?

Comment: Create compound index (hashed_word, indexVal) - in this way you will read all data needed from the index. This is called `index covered query`

Comment: Thanks. My database knowledge is very low, because I am in Computer Vision and High Performance Computing area. Can you please help me with query, step step?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE key_word DROP INDEX hashed_word, ADD INDEX (hashed_word, indexVal)`

Answer (score 1):

You could try to make an index over `hashed_word` and `indexVal` (in that order).

This index will be fast for selecting based on a criterion on `hashed_word` AND the index includes `indexVal` in its index data so the data does not need to be read from the disk.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this seems like creating 2 indexes at once? How can I do this?

Comment: I have not tested but I think the following should work: `ALTER TABLE key_word ADD INDEX val_hashed (hashed_word,indexVal);` (You create not two indices but one index with two columns in the right order.) (The `val_hashed` is just a name for the new index, you can leave this out or choose this freely.)